# Gcc complains about vstmia - why?

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, raspberry-pi2, neon

I'm trying to compile a program for Raspberry Pi 2B (ARMv7 / Neon), but I get an error from an inline assembly code:

> Error: VFP single precision register expected -- `vstmia.64
>   r9,{d16-d31}'

The code is:

```
asm volatile (
        "vstmia.64 %[reg]!, {d0 - d15} @ read all regs\n\t"
        "vstmia.64 %[reg], {d16 - d31} @ read all regs\n\t"
        ::[reg] "r" (&vregs):
);
```

Funny thing is that it doesn't complain about the first `vstmia`.
I tried with single `{d0 - d32}` first and I thought maybe there were too many 64-bit registers, but that's obviously not the problem.
`vregs` is a 8-byte aligned storage.

I'm using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc 4.8.3, with this command line:

> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a7 -marm -O2 -g -std=gnu11 -MMD -MP -MF"ARM_decode_table.d" -MT"ARM_decode_table.o" -c -o "ARM_decode_table.o" "../ARM_decode_table.c"

Comment: What `-mfpu=` option are you passing?

Comment: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a7 -marm -O2  -g -std=gnu11 -MMD -MP -MF"ARM_decode_table.d" -MT"ARM_decode_table.o" -c -o "ARM_decode_table.o" "../ARM_decode_table.c"

Comment: OK, if you don't specify an FPU you'll get whatever default the compiler was configured with (you can check GCC's configuration with `-v`). I'm gonna throw out a wild guess that that happens to be `vfpv3-d16` ;)

Comment: -v gave me (a lot of stuff among which this) --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard I should change the fpu to neon-vfpv4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By not specifying an appropriate `-mfpu` option, you get whatever FPU support the compiler's default configuration provides. From your configuration in this case, that is `--with-fpu=vfp`, which means crusty old VFPv2 with only 16 D registers overlaying the 32 S registers. Thus the first instruction targeting `d0`-`d15` is fine, but the assembler refuses to assemble the second instruction which it knows won't work on the chosen target.

For Cortex-A7 with NEON, `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4` will let the toolchain know that it can let rip and use everything you have available.

Comment: A-ha. Looks like eclipse didn't add that flag even if I selected it. Adding it manually did the trick.

Comment: You should consider replacing vldmia with vld1.64 if you can meet the alignment conditions. VLD1/VST1 are faster by a good margin when combined with alignment specifiers.